# char pointer value in array

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code which gets some char tokens with strtok and it keeps these tokens one by one in a table and finally print these tokens. My error is in TABLE line:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char* to 'char''
```

Something I misunderstood about the pointers and characters and I do not know how to write the TABLE line ((which I want to have the following format)). I tried something like

```
table[i][5+(i/2)] = *ptr;
```

but I had segmentation fault.

```
i = 0;
int offset = 5;
char* ptr;
ptr = strtok(buff,"do something");
char table[1][10];       
while (ptr != NULL)
 {
  if (i == 0)
     strcat(machine, ptr);
  if (i == 2)
     strcat(number, ptr);
  if (i == 4)
     strcat(hr, ptr); 
  if (i == 6)
     strcat(dw, ptr); 
  if (i == 8)
     strcat(vcc, ptr);
  ptr = strtok(NULL,"do something");
  table[i][5+(i/2)] = ptr;     
  i++;
 }
printf("Final: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", machine, number, hr, dw, vcc);
```

Comment: `table[i][5+(i/2)] = *ptr;` is correct. The segmentation fault is because `i` exceeds the table dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table[i][5+(i/2)] = ptr;`  is wrong because you are trying to assign address instead of value.

`table[i][5+(i/2)] = *ptr;` is correct. It will give the value at the `ptr`.

*Segmentation fault* is because of `i`. it is referring an address which is out of array boundary.

Comment: so you purpose me to increase the dimensions of the array??

Comment: @dali1985 No! You should make sure that `i` doesn't exceed the dimensions. This indicates that your logic is not good, you should reconsider the loop and perform some checks before inserting a value to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing some variables, and memory setup's.
the variable ***machine*** should allocate enough memory, to store your strings in it.
same for ***number***, ***hr***, ***dww***, and ***vcc***.
Then, your ***table*** variable has coded, that only one (1) entry can exists in it - in other words: your table[1] is invalid, because it has not enough room, to "add" pointers to it.
The array after table[1] - also the [10] ***( table[1][10] )*** indicates each table item (here, only one) that have it 10 bytes in length/size.
So, you just write a "char" array, which can contain ten(10) characters.
Which give a "static" literal/string.

As this, you can be lucky, if you don't get a system fault.
But table seems be irrelevant, because your last code line, so far i can see this, only print ***number***, ***hr***, ***dww***, and ***vcc*** on screen.

But this is not the mistake alone.
Before all this code, you should get a crash at

```
char *ptr;
ptr = strtok(buff,"do something");
```

because you don't allocate memory for ptr, one line above.